# Java2D and Swing Not Outputing Images with JFrames and JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, java-2d

I am working on the basics of a graphics program in swing and java2D to practice. I am having a problem wherein I cannot show my images. I have divided my code into 4 classes so that when the program gets larger it's easier to manage.

The idea is that I have very little in the Main, that Frame initializes my first screen, that the screens can all be subdivided into their own classes, TitleScreen being one of these, and PullImage does all of the work of buffering and printing images which bothered me.

When I run this I get an empty window and no errors, so I cannot figure out where the problem is.

Please and Thank you for your help.

Main

```
package com.game.pack;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public final static void main(String[] args) 
{

    new Frame().initialize();
    new TitleScreen().openScreen();

}
}
```

Frame

```
package com.game.pack;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public final void initialize()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    panel.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public final void close()
{
    dispose();
}

}
```

TitleScreen

```
package com.game.pack;

public class TitleScreen {

    public void openScreen()
    {
        new PullImage().printARGB("icons/titleBG.png",800,600,0,0);
        new PullImage().printARGBFromSheet("icons/titleButtons.png",
            200, 125, 400, 200, 200, 40, 0, 0);
        while (1!=2)
    {
}
```

PullImage

```
package com.game.pack;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class PullImage {

public void printARGB(String source, int sizeX, int sizeY, int locX, int locY)
{
    Image Icon = new ImageIcon(source).getImage();
    BufferedImage BuffedImage = new BufferedImage(sizeX, sizeY, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = BuffedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(Icon,locX,locY,null);
}

public void printARGBFromSheet(String source, int sizeX, int sizeY, int locX, int locY, int width, int height, int sheetLocX, int sheetLocY)
{
    Image Icon = new ImageIcon(source).getImage();
    BufferedImage BuffedImage = new BufferedImage(sizeX,sizeY,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics graphics = BuffedImage.getGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(Icon, locX, locY, locX+width, locY+height, sheetLocX, sheetLocY, sheetLocX+width, sheetLocY+height, null);
}


}
```

Comment: So far, I've see no attempt to renderer anything to the screen, where's the `paintXxx` methods??  I'd suggest you need to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) for more information

Comment: I was under the impression that that was done by graphics.drawImage. Does it not do that? What does it do then?

Comment: 1) Wow!  You read both those tutorials mentioned by @MadProgrammer in just 3 minutes?!? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @user1784254 Yes it is, but what are your drawing to?  You're not drawing to the screen

Comment: Why does `Main` and `Frame` subclass `JFrame`?

Comment: You extending `Jframe` to your `Main` Class and to your `Frame` Class and then you creating a new instance of `JFrame` inside the `initialize()` method of the `Frame` Class, doesn't this appears strange to you, as to why you doing, what you doing ? Moreover, if you look closely and try to understand your code, you are drawing with the graphics object of the `BufferedImage`, but you never added this `BufferedImage` to any component anywhere, this `BufferedImage` is still invisible, so how you expecting it to be visible anywhere ? Ask these questions to yourself, you will find an answer soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

One problem lies here:

```
public final void initialize()
{  
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

This is setting the content pane of your frame to the panel, not the JFrame you created. Essentially you're not adding it to the actual visible window. Just replace it with

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```